# Cython - Initialize a vector[int] with a python list

Tags: list, cython

I'd like to create a list of integers, implemented as a C++ vector, and initialize it as an empty (python) list.
However, compiling the code

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef vector[int] s = []
```

leads to the following compilation error: `prova.pyx:3:21: Cannot coerce list to type 'vector[int]'`.

Also

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef vector[int] s
s = []
```

leads to the same error.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this got quite a lot a views over time, let's answer even though it's old:

```
cdef vector[int] s
```

automatically initializes an empty `vector[int]`, which is equivalent to an empty list (e.g. `print("empty" if not s else "filled")` would print "empty").

However, due to the `cdef`, `s` is a c++ `vector` which cannot be converted to/from a `PyObject` (which `[]` is).
This is why the assignment does not work **inside the .pyx**.

The seamless conversion between c++ vectors and python lists occurs only inside python scripts (i.e. inside a **.py**, and **not** a .pyx) where you would have imported a something that returns or owns `s`.

Comment: currently Nov 2021 from my testing on latest Cython, the assignment of the OP is legal in Cython

Comment: `cdef vector[int] t = []` doesn't work but struct assignment works: `cdef struct t = {"prop1":value1, "prop2":value2}`